# DJANGO, MTTP Comments, IntegrityError

Tags: django, comments

Hi I get this error when I try to insert this comment into my MTTP. I am using MTTP and not MTTP-Comments. Please help!

```
IntegrityError at /tasks/3264/
(1452, 'Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails 
(`taskdb`.`tasks_comment`, CONSTRAINT `task_id_refs_id_1c5648d2` FOREIGN KEY      
(`task_id`) REFERENCES `tasks_task` (`id`))')
```

My model is:

```
class Task(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        app_label = 'tasks'
        ordering = ('taskid',)

    # meta
    taskid = models.IntegerField(default=0, db_index=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % self.taskid

class Comment(MPTTModel):
    task = models.ForeignKey(Task)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    comment = models.TextField()
    added  = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    # a link to comment that is being replied, if one exists
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='children')

    class MPTTMeta:
        order_insertion_by=['added']
```

My view is:

```
if request.POST:
    comment = Comment(
        author=request.POST['author'],
        comment=request.POST['comment'],
        task_id='3264',
    )
    comment.save()
```

My HTML is:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" value="" name="author">
    <textarea name="comment"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Add comment"> </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

So, what about question is? It seems like no record in Task table with id=3264.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good idea to put task id in Comment creation .
You need to get Task instance before.

So, try this:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
task = get_object_or_404(Task, pk=3264)

comment = Comment.objects.create (
        author=request.POST['author'],
        comment=request.POST['comment'],
        task=task,
    )
```

And check if Task with this id really exists.